# How to ask MySQL to prompt for values in a query?

Tags: mysql, console

I am doing a lot of trial and error with some SQL query in MySQL console e.g.

```
select fname, age, address from person where lname = ?;
```

I want to get a prompt asking me for the value of lname, so that I can repeat the query with different values easily. The ? works in case the query is from Java code.

Is it possible in MySQL console, if yes, how?

Comment: If you had the database hosted on a server, wouldn't it just be easier to make a simple PHP interface?

Comment: Try `@lname` instead `?`.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Nope, doesn't work.

Comment: @Phorce Probably, I don't know PHP, and would like to know if it's possible in MySQL console directly or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible.

You may want to create a stored procedure such as

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE GetPerson(p_lname VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
    SELECT fname, age, address FROM person WHERE lname = p_lname;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

and then be able to

```
mysql> CALL GetPerson('smith');
```

But this is pretty much as far as you can go.

`mysql` client's purpose is to run SQL queries (and manage the service), SQL is a query language, not meant for user interaction.